Can a LZW implementation be correct yet not optimal?
I am used to compressing my TIFF images to gain storage space. This compression is internal - I use the excellent ImageMagick CLI tool with the -compress lzw flags to have the image data be compressed in the file.
I am building an image management tool using rust and there is a TIFF handler library. Unfortunately, when trying it out, it turns out compressing TIFF images with it actually makes them bigger ! The images are still valid however so it is not corrupting anything.
I am trying to account for this difference of results using the same compression algorithm. Should I look for errors in the rust LZW encoder ? Can it produce unoptimized yet correct LZW compression ? Or should I look for pre/post optimizations made by ImageMagick that help in this regard ?
You can see here the original, the copy compressed with the image-rs project and ImageMagick.
-rw-r--r--   1 jb staff  57M Jul 26 15:47 original.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 jb staff  67M Aug  1 16:07 image-rs.tiff
-rw-r--r--   1 jb staff  44M Aug  1 16:07 magick.tiff

It is important to note that all three of those images are identical when opened with image viewers.
I dug a little bit in the code of the LZW encoder used by the rust version, and sure enough each subdivision of the image (strips) are "compressed" to a bigger size:
# Log traces added to the source; sizes are in bytes:  input -> output
2024-08-02T12:01:37.032Z TRACE [weezl::encode] Done: 1012584 -> 1153508
2024-08-02T12:01:37.048Z TRACE [weezl::encode] Done: 1012584 -> 1155616
2024-08-02T12:01:37.063Z TRACE [weezl::encode] Done: 1012584 -> 1157896
2024-08-02T12:01:37.077Z TRACE [weezl::encode] Done: 1012584 -> 1157644

Looking at the exif headers, I can see that the LZW encoder in magick is able to get those same strips to a smaller size. The first strip is only 840183 bytes and this average compression ratio is consistent.

Compression doesn't always result in smaller files, for example consider this simple run length encoded string "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" coud be encoded as "16a" or as "1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a" doubling it's length, yet both are valid representations of the same string, while LZW is a lot more sophisticated, it together with all losless compression works on the premise that the original data has some redundancy that can be reduced by finding patterns and hence is suceptible to equivalent subobtimal "compression" cornercases.

There is probably a better dupe around than: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410153/lzw-compression-doesnt-seem-to-work-correctly

Yes and we are seeing this here. However both compressors are implementing the same procedure, and the algorithm is not that open to interpretation, yet the results differ wildly. I guess my question is for LZW specifically, what can account for this difference in results ?

You might try running exiftool -v3 IMAGE.TIF on your 2 images produced by the 2 different tools to see any differences - including strip byte counts etc.

Thanks to Mark Setchell I noticed the rust implementation lacking a predictor, and this is the step that was missing to have the compression go the extra mile in the case of TIFF/LZW. Both implementations were correct after all ! It was just about preparing the data.
